# How can I change the bounce of SKSpriteNode dynamically?

Tags: swift, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have a very simple app. All SKSpriteNodes, myBall, myBlue, and myRed.

Only myBall moves, affected by gravity, and bounces off of different objects (myRed and myBlue).

What I can't figure out is how to make myBall bounce harder or softer depending on which body it hits?

I hav been playing with the density of all the objects, but it doesn't seem to make any difference? Is there some property I am unaware of? Or are there other methods?

[image]

Comment: You could maybe look at [restitution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520447-restitution), which is how bouncy an object is. Change the value on myRed and myBlue and see what happens.

Comment: @JohnL I've done this, but nothing has changed. Does the restitution of the blocks count? Because that is what I am trying to do, make different blocks bounce the ball back differently? Or is there a cumulative affect of the restitution of both?

Comment: Ok. Change the restitution of the ball to a larger value than 1, to make sure that it indeed does have a noticeable affect. I guess one way which would work is in your physics didBegin, determine what block the ball is hitting, then change the balls restitution accordingly.

Comment: Forget the larger than 1 restitution. I have just done a test. I had the ball as 0.5 restitution, when changing the ground block from 0.2 to 0.8 restitution it changed how high the ball bounces. So the ball can bounce differently depending on what block it hits.